# DrawerArrowToggle animation for the Drawer Navigation bar

Tags: android, animation, navigation-drawer

I want to use Google's animation to turn the navigation icon to an arrow upon opening of the navigation bar and turn it back to a drawer navigation icon. I am also wondering if I can keep the action bar stationary when moving to another activity.

---EDIT---

This question is out of date and no longer relevant as the navigation drawer in material design has been provided for developers in an easy and seemless process that no longer requires developers to add the hamburger side menu to back arrow animation as it is already provided.

```
     menutitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sidebar);
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.slider_list);

            mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.list_tem, R.id.title, menutitles));
            // Set the list's click listener
            mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                    R.mipmap.drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

                /**
                 * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state.
                 */
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }

                /**
                 * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state.
                 */
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }
            };

            // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    /**   * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during   * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...   */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    /** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                break;
            case 1: Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Time.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                finish();
                break;
            case 2: Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Temperature.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
                finish();
                break;
            case 3: Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, Weight.class);
                startActivity(intent4);
                finish();
                break;
            case 4: Intent intent5 = new Intent(this, Length.class);
                startActivity(intent5);
                finish();
                break;
            case 5: Intent intent6 = new Intent(this, Money.class);
                startActivity(intent6);
                finish();
                break;
            case 6:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Metric.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                finish();
                break;
            case 7:
                Intent intent7 = new Intent(this, Food.class);
                startActivity(intent7);
                finish();
                break;
            case 8:
                Intent intent8 = new Intent(this, Data.class);
                startActivity(intent8);
                finish();
                break;
        }
        // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position


        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle("Converjz");
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }




    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: Well I've been looking at Material Design for Android where the navigation drawer can change to a back arrow through animation. I can't find a straightforward answer to this question so I'm personally asking how to add it to my code that I have above. Nothing is wrong with the code, I want to easily add it to my code.

Comment: You're using the v4 support version of the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. If you want the hamburger-arrow animation, you need to use the [v7 appcompat version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html).

Comment: Ok, is there an easy way to edit this an change to version 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to use Google's animation to turn the navigation icon to an arrow upon opening of the navigation bar and turn it back to a drawer navigation icon

Looking at the constructor call, it's evident that you're using the v4 support version of the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. If you want the hamburger-arrow animation, you need to use the v7 appcompat version.

To do this, first add the v7 appcompat library to your project. Then, in the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` `import` statement, change `v4` to `v7`, and drop the `R.mipmap.drawer` argument in the constructor call.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
...

mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
    R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {...}
```

> I am also wondering if I can keep the action bar stationary when moving to another activity.

If you want to use the Navigation Drawer pattern, you should be using `Fragment`s for the different sections, rather than opening a new `Activity` for each. Given the comments in your code, the example you've followed demonstrates how to do that.

Comment: I changed everything and it works now but I have one more problem I have an activity which when created it creates a back button in the action bar. I've seeen the animation happen in gmail when clicking on an individual email and going back. How can i do the same thing?